# How can I calculate factor scores with R?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am doing factor analysis with principal component method in SPSS. As we know, we can get factor scores in SPSS through click "scores" and "save as variables". My question is, i need to get factors scores in R in order to doing more works, so how can i get the same factor scores as in SPSS by R?

Comment: There must be an internaly generated dataset of these. Please read the documentation of the factor analysis function. This question is off-topic here.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html) useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
pcaResult<-princomp(data)
pc=pcaResult$scores
```